# How to type async function using typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using typescript and nlp.js/
But the argument manager says 'Parameter manager implicitly has an any type.
I tried to use : but it doesn't work well.
How can I type in this case? Thank you for reading it.

```
module.exports = async function trainnlp(manager) {
  await manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.arrival', "I've missed you");

  manager.save('./model.nlp', true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to type async function using typescript

The type of an `async` function's return value is `Promise<X>`, where `X` is the fulfillment value that will be provided. In your case, since your function doesn't have a `return` anywhere, it would be `Promise<void>`, since the promise created by your function will be fulfilled with nothing in particular. (At runtime the fulfillment value will be `undefined`, but for type purposes, it's modelled as `Promise<void>`.)

Recent versions of TypeScript will default that return type for you, which is why the error relates to `manager`...

> But the argument manager says 'Parameter manager implicitly has an any type.

This is the real issue with that code: `manager` has no type. The point of TypeScript is to provide strong typing at compile-time. It can't do that for your `trainnlp` function if you don't tell it what type `manager` should be. You want to provide a type for `manager`:

```
// (Just an example type)
interface Manager {
    addAnswer(a: string, b: string, c: string): Promise<void>;
    save(a: string, b: boolean): void;
}

async function trainnlp(manager: Manager) {
// ----------------------------^^^^^^^^^
  await manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.arrival', "I've missed you");

  manager.save('./model.nlp', true);
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJxHA5tZBvAKGWOTgBMyBBEAZwHdoAKOALmRrClCwBpkAjNhy4heyBEM7cAlGwAKUAPYBbYDQgAeAG6LgZAHwBuIiRpwtEZpJFjBAxYoA2EDLOQ69xgL4E4NAJ4gCMgwAK5BYMCKIMiccKAgjgAOjMoY2NBs6Jg4UNL4JnB08WDIaTnQAHTkVLQMUIwA5BAgjXyNWFAQEJGiNNVQXFpwjm3IAEQAko0WZWrqZMj+iqHj0sYm5RlQlWYWTZUA9MqKZBCOlYlJY5yhEOsEXkA)

That clears the problem the error is flagging up. TypeScript will then infer the return type of the function, since it sees that it's an `async` function but never uses `return`, so its type is unambiguously `Promise<void>`.

Comment: is function return nothing

Comment: @constraintAutomaton - I don't understand that...question? `async` functions **always** return a Promise.

Comment: No he wants to wait for is a promise to be completed before saving is `manager`, plus it's not really a question of `async` I'm pretty sure it's the typescript compiler. 
The error is `Parameter manager implicitly has any type` and `manager` is the parameter of is function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your function returns nothing, it has no return statement. the
`addAnswer(a: string, b: string, c: string)` return a promise but it doesn't need a type because the expression is not declared in a variable or the return statement of a function.

Comment: @constraintAutomaton - I suggest reading up on `async` functions. Again, `async` functions **always** return a Promise. That's how they propagate results (specifically in this case, success [fulfillment] or failure [rejection]). The type of `trainnlp` is `Promise<void>` (but as I said in the answer above, that type can be inferred by the compiler, it doesn't need to be explicitly provided).

Answer (score -1):

It's not an async function problem, it's a [compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) problem. In your `tsconfig.json` you have the flag `noImplicitAny` as `true` you can turn it to `false`. But it's a bad idea, for such a trivial case.

A better way to do it would be to specify the type of `manager` you can even set it to `any` if you really want, but I don't think you want it.

```
module.exports = async function trainnlp(manager:any) {
  await manager.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.arrival', "I've missed you");

  manager.save('./model.nlp', true);
}
```